# Convert Distance Along an Irregular Path (Google Earth) to coordinates

Tags: r, google-earth

I have an irregular path along a river from Google Earth. That path has lots of lat/longs defining it, which I can extract from GE.

Given a distance along that path from the known start point which defines a position of interest, how can I convert that position into XY lat long coordinates? I guess this is a basic thing but I can't find any solution. I would much appreciate any advice. An r package? Or can I do it in GE?

```
149.055636737367,-35.45112927380671 149.0554865040784,-35.45700190055306 
149.0588732694746,-35.45963843202778 149.0614163226262,-35.46089587788505 
149.0643983304351,-35.46344348678852 149.0636894528921,-35.4664464644639 
149.0621283100664,-35.46921683868204 149.0598735226898,-35.47361586901361 
149.0600168530359,-35.47511725395636 149.062982189803,-35.47834293008773 
149.066383583204,-35.48099798038856 149.0668090953968,-35.48411619363673
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latitude/longitude for the starting **and** ending points of the Google Earth path?

Comment: Yes. I get them by pasting the GE path into text editor. After a bit of a tidy they look like this but for some reasons the longs are before the lats. 149.055636737367,-35.45112927380671
149.0554865040784,-35.45700190055306
149.0588732694746,-35.45963843202778
149.0614163226262,-35.46089587788505
149.0643983304351,-35.46344348678852
149.0636894528921,-35.4664464644639
149.0621283100664,-35.46921683868204
149.0598735226898,-35.47361586901361
149.0600168530359,-35.47511725395636
149.062982189803,-35.47834293008773
149.066383583204,-35.48099798038856
149.0668090953968,-35.48411619363673

Comment: If you have the lat/long for both the starting and ending point, then what are you trying to find?

Comment: I was going to post an image but my newbyness would not allow it. 'Irregular' in the OP might be better expressed as meandering.

Comment: Given only a starting point in lat/long and a distance alone would only allow you to specify a circle on which the ending point would be found.  Can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Sorry -  the distance is **not** a straight line. It is a meander along the irregular path.

Comment: May I ask how you extracted the coordinates of the river from the GE object?  I'd like to do the same for roads from a Googlemap.  Second, can you create a segmented "line" that changes direction with each coordinate point of the river?

Comment: I think the segmented line idea is an approach to solution. In this case I extracted the coordinates manually (pasting the copied object into text) but I will automate that for my r solution for larger cases. It is just a bit of munging from the xml text.

Comment: Although I have not yet found (or written) the ideal solution yet the r package:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverdist/vignettes/riverdist_vignette.html might be able to solve this issue. It is a package with many features, so has a reasonable learning curve.